# Google Maps hides a map for print preview

Tags: css, google-maps

I am trying to display Google Maps on print preview. If I change .gmnoprint class from display:none to display:inline, I see a map control, a pin, google logo, but still no map. It's blank. How do I make my map to show up for printing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to use the [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=en#quick_example) for print.

Answer (score 4):

In my case (i'm using both Biostall Codeigniter Google Maps V3 API and Google Maps V3 API), i fix the issue using **CSS**. In my deep research, it causes the unfixed/uncertainties of width of the map that "maybe" depends on your div container's width or "maybe again" the map width itself; other web developer's conclusion is it's about bootstrap issue.

```
@media print {
    img {
        max-width: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. The best answer!

Comment: @EricLagarda thanks buddy, dont forget to rate up my answer (y)